# Cual es el mejor proceso para debuggear un memory leak o crash application en ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, servidor, rendimiento

básicamente quería consultar lo del titulo, pero para dejar un poco más de detalles, tenemos una aplicación en dos servidores, los requests le llegan por un `Load Balancer` con el algoritmo `Round Robin` configurado.

El proceso `w3wp.exe` de windows ha llegado a un uso de 90% de `CPU` y 6 gb de uso de `RAM` , el servidor tiene 8 GB de `RAM` y 8 nucleos.

Llega a un instante y la aplicación crashea o la performance baja considerablemente lo que hace inutilizable a la aplicación, ¿Como puedo obtener el proceso exacto que produce el memory leak y disparo de CPU?

[image: Recursos elevado]

Edit: Dejo una imagen con un diagnotico de `Debug Diag` con unos `warnings` donde se puede observar `threads blocked`.

[image: Análisis debug diag]

Dejo un link con la información de `Debug Diag` click [aquí](http://www.mediafire.com/file/s8zf4h1aa4v3haq/warnings-hangandcrash-dump.html)

Cualquier detalle que necesiten pueden pedir y se los brindaría sin problema

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Supongo que no puedes debuggear directamente en el servidor, así que podridas ir creando un log antes y después de cada acción, así podrías ver en que método se traba y tarda en ser terminado.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacer algo al respecto?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, para detectar bien estos problemas es necesario usar algún apm como new relic o lean sentry, de esta manera podrías tener un detalle más eficiente de que linea de código genera el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la herramienta **Debug Diagnostic Tool** para diagnosticar un memory leak, crash de la app, bajo rendimiento, etc...

[Debug Diagnostic Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798)

Para obtener ejemplos de cómo usarla:

[Using Debug Diagnostic Tool v2.0 to troubleshoot IIS problems](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/02/25/using-debug-diagnostic-tool-v2-0-to-troubleshoot-iis-problems/)

Comment: Hola @david_rprada, he intentado utilizarla y he encontrado varios warnings, muchos de estos eventos indican al parecer métodos a bajo nivel u obtiene datos en sectores de memoria difíciles de interpretar. Puedes explicar como interpretar la información con debug diag y que esta interpretación ayude a la solución de inconvenientes?

Comment: No tengo apenas experiencia utilizando la herramienta, pero si puedes añadir los dumps o warnings generados, puedo tratar de ayudarte a identificar los problemas, también me interesa aprender a manejar bien esta herramienta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he actualizado con más información.

Comment: Los warnings del análisis no parecen tener importancia o relación con el alto consumo de memoria del server. En la pestaña Processes del Debug Diagnostic Tool, puedes poner el resultado del Monitor for Leaks para el proceso w3wp.exe?? y probar a hacer el attach debugger sobre el proceso w3wp.exe. Quizás nos de una información más útil